# How do I ask a question about a problem with .xib file?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

For those of you who don't know, `.xib` is the extension of files produced by Apple's GUI builder, aptly named 'Interface Builder'.

I have a programming problem/question: I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` somewhere deep in the call stack, and it is caused by `NSValueBinder`. I tried to debug it but failed, so I wanted to ask about it on Stack Overflow. Now I have a problem: I set up the bindings causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in Interface Builder and `.xib` files are not edited as text. They are edited with the GUI of Interface Builder. In fact, until now, I didn't even know what the underlying format was<sup>1</sup>. So I don't know how to post my `.xib` file in such a way others can inspect them and point out problems.

- Can I ask my question on Stack Overflow without being able to concisely post the problem file?
  Of course, I can provide screenshots and respond to information requests, but I am not sure if that is feasible.
- If I can, how do I include the .xib file? (What information do I give, in what form, etc.)

1: It happens to be XML, but it isn't fit for posting (or reading):[image: The raw .xib file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to debug it but failed, so I wanted to ask about it on StackOverflow.

It sounds like you will have to ask a slightly more general question on how to debug problems with XIB files in Interface Builder.

Some might quibble and kvetch about such questions breaking our guidelines. You know, the ones that say you need to ask about *specific* problems. But in this case, I think it is perfectly justified.

You could certainly ask a question where you dumped the entire XIB file into the body and asked someone to debug it for you. (Well, I don't know. It would probably get closed with the shiny new "this site is not a debugging service; post a *minimal* example" close reason.) But assume you could. Then the problem is, how would that question or its answers ever be useful in the future to someone else? (Which, come to think of it, is the reason we now have that close reason.)

If instead you asked a slightly more general question about how to debug problems given the information you do have, you'd get a slightly more general answer that would be broadly applicable. It would be helpful both for you right now and for others in the future.

I'm not really proposing that you break new ground here. We already encourage people to do this when creating canonical questions as dupe-closure targets for new "debug my code" questions. You'd be doing the same thing, except with a tinge of selfish motive. I say go for it. I trust you to do this, since you were smart enough to ask about it on Meta first.

Comment: "Some might quibble and kvetch about such questions breaking our guidelines." Such people are definitely misguide(line)d. It's hard to see how a good answer to that sort of a question would not be useful to other people.