# How to post iOS Storyboards in my posts?

Tags: support, images, posting

I recently started iOS programming with Swift and I had some problems. So I decided to ask on Stack Overflow. However, I could not find a neat way to post my Storyboards in my question.

I have tried to zoom out to 50% or 25% and post it as an image. But then people would not be able to see the segues and `UIView`s in the Storyboard.

I also tried to cut the Storyboard into pieces and post a screenshot of each. But then the view controllers would occupy the whole image and I would not be able to show segues.

Can you tell me how to properly post a Storyboard in my posts?

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what a storyboard is and why is more important than the code itself?

Comment: It shows the segues and view controllers, right? How can I explain these by words? @Braiam

Comment: *why is more important than the code itself* @Braiam - Because you don't look at the code behind views in Xcode. It isn't like with Android programming where you're usually messing in the actual XML. (Or maybe some people do, but I never did and I can't imagine posting the actual code for those would be useful for most people.)

Comment: @Braiam - [This is an iOS Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AboutStoryboards.html). And this isn't to say there isn't a way for the OP to describe what's happening; just that posting the code for these probably isn't helpful.

Comment: @BSMP remember me again the good old times where I just had to describe the interface and a library took care of the rest.

Comment: Similar question for `xib`: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261045/how-do-i-ask-a-question-about-a-problem-with-xib-file

Comment: Maybe your question is too broad if we need the storyboard? There has been a somwhat related discussion on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/how-to-support-questions-about-development-environments-that-rely-on-more-than-c)

Comment: Related: [How do I ask a question about a problem with xib file?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261045)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the good questions and answers I see only post screenshots of their Storyboards to reinforce or clarify something that isn't completely clear in plain text. I'd suggest focusing on the question first, then go back and see if a screenshot of all your Storyboards really helps improve the question or if it just adds noise.

You can find plenty of great examples of how others have included screenshots of Storyboards in their questions and answers by simply [searching Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Storyboard) on SO. I personally like how this [user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/2108547) included what was only necessary and highlighted/cropped in on what was important.